# IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'credential' available as request attribute

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this thymeleaf template snippet:

```html
    <form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{/credentials}" th:object="${credential}">
        <input type="hidden" name="credentialId" th:field="*{credentialId}" id="credential-id">
    </form>
```

and this data class:

```java
 

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Credential {
        private Integer credentialId;
        private String url;
        private String userName;
        private String key;
        private String password;
        private Integer userid;
    }
```

I can't figure out why I am getting this error since the `credentialId` property exists in the credentials:Credential object. I also make sure to add `credentials` to my Model

I have tried making sure that what I see in the template corresponds to what I have in the backend and I do not observe any differences.

Answer (score 0):

*I also make sure to add credentials to my Model*

In your view you are not using credentials that you said you are placing in your Model object, you are using credential

th:object value must match with the Model from your controller.